# Address Variables with PowerShell and Import-CSV foreach-loop

Tags: variables, powershell

Input file:

```
"Server1","lanmanserver"
"Server2","lanmanserverTest"
```

Program

```
$csvFilename = "D:\Scripts\ServerMonitorConfig.csv" 
$csv = Import-Csv $csvFilename -Header @("ServerName","ServiceName")

foreach ($line in $csv) {
    Write-Host "ServerName=$line.ServerName  ServiceName=$line.ServiceName" 
    }
```

What I want:

> Server-Name=Server1  ServiceName=lanmanserver
>   Server-Name=Server2  ServiceName=lanmanserverT

What I'm getting:

> ServerName=@{ServerName=Server1; ServiceName=lanmanserver}.ServerName 
>   ServiceName=@{ServerName=Server1; ServiceName=lanmanserver}.ServiceN
>   ame ServerName=@{ServerName=Server2;
>   ServiceName=lanmanserverTest}.ServerName 
>   ServiceName=@{ServerName=Server2; ServiceName=lanmanserverTest}.
>   ServiceName

I really don't care if the Headers come from the first row of the CSV or not, I'm flexible there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You usually see subexpressions or format strings used to solve that:

Subexpression:

```
Write-Host "ServerName=$($line.ServerName)  ServiceName=$($line.ServiceName)"
```

Format string:

```
Write-Host ('ServerName={0}   ServiceName={1}' -f $line.ServerName,$line.ServiceName)
```

Comment: I knew it had to be simple.  So what is $line.ServerName, and why does it need the extra $() around it?

Comment: This is where I'm really going with this:     Write-Host "ServerName=$($line.ServerName)  ServiceName=$($line.ServiceName)" 
    $status = (get-service -Name $line.ServiceName -ComputerName $line.ServerName).Status  So it looks like I only $() inside the quotes.

Comment: It's just the way the parser works on double quoted strings.  To use a property of an object in an expandable string, the $object.property must be wrapped in $(), making it a subexpression.